# hapi library 'getAll(String name)' doesn't return all custom z-segments from message

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

Ok, so I've implemented a custom ORU_R01 v2.3 message and a custom Z-segment
(called ZDS) using the HAPI library (version 1.2).

They seem to be working well.  However, when I have a message with
multiple ZDS segments, I find I'm unable to get them all.  I call the
'getAll("ZDS");' method, thinking it will return an array of segments
with id ZDS.  However, it will only ever return an array of either
length 0 or 1 (returns length 1 even if there are multiple ZDS segments).

Here's my code in my custom ORU_R01 message that tries to get an array
of ZDS segments:

```
public ZDS[] getZDSList() throws HL7Exception {
        System.out.println("NUM REPS: " + currentReps("ZDS"));
        Structure[] list = getAll("ZDS");
        ZDS[] zdsSegments = new ZDS[list.length];

        for (int i=0; i < list.length; i++)
            zdsSegments[i] = (ZDS) list[i];

        return zdsSegments;
    }
```

The output for currentReps("ZDS") is always either 0 or 1.

I'm learning, but I'm hitting some road blocks.  I'd appreciate any help
you guys can offer!!

Cheers

Jarrett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out, when I add the ZDS segment to my custom ORU_R01, I needed to set the segment to be repeating.  i.e.:

`this.add(ZDS.class, false, false);`

needs to be changed to

`this.add(ZDS.class, false, true);`

and then it works!

Thanks to everyone who checked this out.

Cheers

Jarrett